# Set template name after update_post_meta

Tags: wordpress

How do I set the templates name of the page attributes after I  inserted a post and update the post meta?

```
wp_insert_post( $args );
update_post_meta($page->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'page-contact.php');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `wp_insert_post` [*will return the ID*](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post.php#L2591) of the inserted post. So:

```
$inserted_post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
if( $inserted_post_id )
    update_post_meta( $inserted_post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page-contact.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to change the _wp_page_template value after inserting a new post using the wp_insert_post() function? If that's the case you could try the following:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

see the official [wpdb class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) in WordPress codex for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the post value for `_wp_page_template` with one of these action hooks

1. **pre_post_update** - Runs just before a post or page is updated.
2. **publish_post** - Runs when a post is published, or if it is edited and its status is "published".
3. **save_pos**t - Runs whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email.
4. **wp_insert_post** - Same as save_post, runs immediately afterwards.